# ASP.NET(C#) catching exception while using stored procedure (sql database)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

The code is as follows... I tried using debug points and it shows:

> Procedure or function 'usp_select_legal1_data' expects parameter '@tower', which was not supplied.

C# code:

```
try {
    LegalView.ActiveViewIndex = 2;

    String tw2 = TextBox3.Text;
    SqlDataSource SqlDataSource2 = new SqlDataSource();
    SqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource2";
    this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource2);
    SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("@tower", tw2);
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "usp_select_legal1_data";

    GVCaseTowerWise.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
    GVCaseTowerWise.DataBind();

    if (GVCaseTowerWise.Rows.Count == 0) {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
            this,
            this.GetType(),
            "alertMessage",
            "alert('No cases for this tower exist in the database')",
            true);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
            "alertMessage", "alert('error while getting data')", true);
}
```

And this is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_select_legal1_data]
    @tower nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT distinct
      [tower_to]
      ,[tower_from]
      ,[sy_no]
    FROM [dbo].[legal1]
    WHERE ((tower_to = @tower) or (tower_from = @tower))
END
```

Comment: `tw2` is probably null and `@tower` has no default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. The problem was with defining the stored procedure. it was still treating the procedure as text command. here is what i used

> SqlDataSource2.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;

and now it is working.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("@tower", tw2);
```

to

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("tower", tw2);
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint after `SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("tower", tw2);` and see what `SelectParameters` contains?

Comment: guys...can using the 'using' code to open the connection solve the problem?...if not then can there be any software problem that it isn't returning the value...but using direct commands like "select * from...." gets the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is putting @, because the parameter name is tower. please see the MSDN documentation below
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58z9c1a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: guys...can using the 'using' code to open the connection solve the problem?...if not then can there be any software problem that it isn't returning the value...but using direct commands like "select * from...." gets the correct result.